# Showing Fatal Error when clicked on system->configuration in magento admin

Tags: magento

I have added a google translator in my site.But after adding When i go to system->configuration,the page is not opening showing 
Fatal error: Class 'Ansyori_Autotrans_Helper_Data' not found in /home/vancebla/public_html/Demo/FlooringShack/app/Mage.php on line 546
I tried but didn't find the error.if anybody knows this then please help me out.
thanks!

my config.xml file is below..........

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
  <modules>
    <Ansyori_Autotrans>
      <version>0.1.0</version>
    </Ansyori_Autotrans>
  </modules>
  <frontend>
    <routers>
      <autotrans>
        <use>standard</use>
          <args>
            <module>Ansyori_Autotrans</module>
            <frontName>autotrans</frontName>
          </args>
      </autotrans>
    </routers>
        <layout>
          <updates>
            <autotrans>
              <file>autotrans.xml</file>
            </autotrans>
          </updates>
        </layout>
  </frontend>
  <global>
    <helpers>
      <autotrans>
        <class>Ansyori_Autotrans_Helper</class>
      </autotrans>
    </helpers>
    <blocks>
      <autotrans>
        <class>Ansyori_Autotrans_Block</class>
      </autotrans>
    </blocks>
  </global>
</config>
```

data.php file is below

```
<?php

    class Ansyori_Autotrans_Helper_Data extends Mage_Core_Helper_Abstract {

    }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You're missing your Helper/Data.php file in your module.  Try this:

If your module is in the "local" codePool then go to:  `app/code/local`
If its in the "community" codePool then go to: `app/code/community`

Then go to: `Ansyori/Autotrans/Helper`.  If the `Helper` folder doesn't exist then create it.

Inside the `Helper` folder, create a file called `Data.php`.

Edit `Data.php` and insert the following code:

```
    <?php

        class Ansyori_Autotrans_Helper_Data extends Mage_Core_Helper_Abstract {

        }
?>
```

The entire file path is:  `app/code/local/Ansyori/Autotrans/Helper/Data.php` OR `app/code/community/Ansyori/Autotrans/Helper/Data.php` depending on your module's codePool.

Save the file and see if the error goes away.

Comment: please help me still i have the same problem.system-> configuration page is not opening showing Fatal error: Class 'Ansyori_Autotrans_Helper_Data' not found in app/Mage.php. if anyone knows this,please help me out

Comment: Can you post your `/app/code/local/Ansyori/Autotrans/etc/config.xml` file?

Comment: see my config.xml file above i have posted.......plz tell me where i am commiting mistake.thanks

Comment: The xml looks ok to me.  I can't help but think that you have a typo in your Helper/Data.php file.  Can you post the contents of that file too?

Comment: please check the data.php file above  and tell me if there will be any error.thanks

Comment: The error isn't in your app/Mage.php file.  That is just telling you that there's a problem somewhere else.  I notice that you called the filename `data.php` above.  Please ensure that it is `Data.php` with a capital D.  It is case-sensitive.

Comment: no no it is written as Data.php by mistake i have written data.php....so this is not the error

Comment: Do you have Compilation mode disabled in `Admin -> System -> Tools -> Compilation`?

Comment: Disable it, flush your cache and try again.

Comment: yes it works,thanks a lot! can you please tell me if compilation status is enabled then why this fatal error occured?

Comment: The compiler copies every class in Magento to a folder to speed up access times.  If you have compiler mode on and install a new extension then the compiler will be missing that class from the compiled location.  Once you showed that you did have the Helper/Data in the correct location and defined properly in your xml, then the only possible explanation left was that you have compiler mode enabled.  Always be sure to disable it when installing new extensions.